# C++ nested class instances

Tags: c++, arrays, class, nested, instance

What I have is 2 classes:

**A.h:**

```
#include "B.h"
class A
{
    vector<B*> arr;
    void Update(int32 id){...};
}
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    int32 id;
    A* parent;
    void OnRemove()
    {
        ...
        parent->Update(id);
    }
}
```

With that logic everything must work fine as expected.
But it won't because of `loop include`: `A.h` including `B.h` and `B.h` including `A.h`

The question is how to make it working with that structure of code or other.

Main feature that should exist is to call event in A object which is holding B object.

Every help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure but it looks like this is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declare `class A;` in **B.h** and `class B;` in **A.h**

You should then move the implementation of `onRemove()` to **B.cpp** and include **A.h** here.

Also don't forget your include guards. Example:

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

class B;

class A {

};

#endif
```

The include guards could also be replaced by `#pragma once` at the beginning of the header, this is a little less verbose.

**Edit**

To be complete:

```
// A.h

#pragma once

#include <vector>

class B;
class A {
    std::vector<B*> arr;

public:
    void Update(int32 id);        
};

// A.cpp

#include "A.h"

// possibly #include "B.h" if necessary

void A::Update(int32 id) {
    // impl ...
}

// B.h

#pragma once

class A;
class B
{
    int32 id;
    A* parent;

public:
    void OnRemove();
};

// B.cpp

#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void B::OnRemove() {
    parent->Update(id);
}
```

Well, something like this...

Answer (score 1):

the usual way is to provide guarding macros to prevent recursion and move definition of functions in a separate file if needed:

a.h

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
#include "B.h"
class A
{
  vector<B*> arr;
  void Update(int32 id){...};
} 
#endif
```

...

c.cpp (if needed)

```
#include <a.h>
#include <b.h>

void B::onRemove() {
   blahblahblah
}
```

Comment: So using `guarding macros` is same as using `pragma once`?

Comment: Should I use forward declaration in B.h to make `A* parent` is compiling?

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore folloed by a capital letter (`_A_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Include guards only address part of the problem here. The remaining issue is that class `A` uses `B*` and class `B` uses `A*`; that requires forward declarations.

Comment: So, I should use forward declaration and just include both headers in source cpp file?

Comment: yes, in your case you would also need a forward declaration of `A` or `B` or both.

Comment: also the names of macro were used arbitrary, but they should include file name in a form to make them unique across the whole project.